# How to get each specific value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I'm looking to be able to extract each 'hire_address' value from the following array and add it to a separate array.

```
var addr =
{  
   "status":"success",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "start":"2017-01-26 12:30:00",
         "hire_oucu":"ac2",
         "hire_address":"Glasgow",
         "offer_oucu":"ac1",
         "offer_address":"Glasgow"
      },
      {  
         "start":"2017-01-26 12:30:00",
         "hire_oucu":"ac2",
         "hire_address":"Poole",
         "offer_oucu":"ac1",
         "offer_address":"Poole"
      }
      {  
         "start":"2017-01-26 12:30:00",
         "hire_oucu":"ac2",
         "hire_address":"Hastings",
         "offer_oucu":"ac1",
         "offer_address":"Hastings"
      }
      {  
         "start":"2017-01-26 12:30:00",
         "hire_oucu":"ac2",
         "hire_address":"London",
         "offer_oucu":"ac1",
         "offer_address":"London"
      }
   ]
};
```

I currently have

```
var addresses = [];
$.each(addr.data.hire_address, function (index, value) {
addresses.push(value);
```

But not having any luck. Any suggestions?

Thank you for the replies.

I now have

```
var addresses = [];
$.each(addr, function (index, value) {
    if (value == "data"){
        addresses.push(value.hire_address);
    }
}
);
```

But can't seem to get it to work. Do I need the `if` statement? I added this because the first item is 'status' and was running into errors if I tried to add a 'hire_address' property of this because it doesn't exists.

Comment: You realise you’re missing a few commas? After the first inner object, you don’t have any commas between the rest.

Answer (score 0):

$.each takes two parameters, the first being an array. You should pass in the array you want to loop through.

the second parameter is the function that gets call per item in array. It is stored in the value parameter. If you are looping through the array, you can access the correct property like so:

```
value.hire_address
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

**Use Array.map**

```
addr.data.map(d => d.hire_address)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Array#map()`

```js
var addr = {
  "status": "success",
  "data": [{
      "start": "2017-01-26 12:30:00",
      "hire_oucu": "ac2",
      "hire_address": "Glasgow",
      "offer_oucu": "ac1",
      "offer_address": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
      "start": "2017-01-26 12:30:00",
      "hire_oucu": "ac2",
      "hire_address": "Poole",
      "offer_oucu": "ac1",
      "offer_address": "Poole"
    }, {
      "start": "2017-01-26 12:30:00",
      "hire_oucu": "ac2",
      "hire_address": "Hastings",
      "offer_oucu": "ac1",
      "offer_address": "Hastings"
    }, {
      "start": "2017-01-26 12:30:00",
      "hire_oucu": "ac2",
      "hire_address": "London",
      "offer_oucu": "ac1",
      "offer_address": "London"
    }
  ]
};

let myArray = addr.data.map(d => d["hire_address"]);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you fix up your object (see my comment), you can iterate simply without jQuery:

```
var addresses=[];
addr.data.forEach(function(a){
    addresses.push(a.hire_address);
});
alert(addresses);
```

The JavaScript `.forEach()` array method does a similar job to jQuery’s `.each()` without the overhead.

Alternatively, for older browsers:

```
for(var i=0;i<addr.data.length;i++)
    addresses.push(addr.data[i].hire_address);
```